# How to install OpenCV for C/C++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to install the C/C++ interfaces for OpenCV. I have already installed it for Python, which was a very straightforward process, I just had to issue the command `pip3 install opencv-python` and it got installed.

I have followed many sites on how to install OpenCV for C/C++, but they teach of installing it from the source. Due to my limited bandwidth, I have problems downloading the sources, which are quite large. Is there any other straightforward process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use the package manger `apt`

```
sudo apt-get install -y libopencv-dev
```

and then link your source to the libraries.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way is to use anaconda

```
conda install opencv
```

It will install opencv for python along with c++ headers/libraries and cmake files.

Comment: Hey, I was looking to do this. exactly this. But I can't get my head around linking and including libraries in CMake. Do you have any idea?